# How are fresh fish shipped across continents?

Tags: fish, fresh

I am currently wondering when I see in US fish markets "Fresh Scottish Salmon" or in Europe "Fresh Alaskan Salmon".
How do you ship fresh fish across continents? By plane over night? Or there is no way it will be frozen then not fresh?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the fish is fresh (not frozen) then it will typically be put in insulated or double-insulated packaging with dry ice and/or gel packs and flown to its destination.

Comment: If there is dry ice, it will freeze the fish.